# Apache mod_rewrite RewriteRule not being picked up

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use RewriteRule to redirect one URL to another (**edited with updated examples**)

I have the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule old-url new-url [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cID\=164
RewriteRule (.*) new-url [R=307,L,QSD]
```

These both work in my `.htaccess` file. However, I want these rules in my `httpd.conf` file (via an include). I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

<Directory /home/staging/web/>
RewriteRule old-url new-url [L,R=307]
RewriteRule /old-url new-url [L,R=307]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cID\=164
RewriteRule (.*) new-url [R=307,L,QSD]
</Directory>
```

The URL redirect doesn't work with or without the leading `/`, and the query string rule doesn't work either, despite being the same as in the `.htaccess` file. I am using the `<Directory>` block as I read this should make it be treated as if it were in a `.htaccess` file, however it does not seem to.

How can I use RewriteRule in the `httpd.conf` file and have the same functionality as when used in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You don't need to use 2 directives . Just use `RewriteRule` and put this at the top of your htaccess bellow `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: I know I don't need both, the whole point of the question is that using `RewriteRule` does not work, whereas `redirect` does, which is what I am trying to understand.

Comment: If you are using `RewriteRule` directive in htaccess context then you will have to use a relative url path in pattern.  so change `/oldurl` to `oldurl` in the pattern of your Rule

Comment: That works in the htaccess, thank you, but ideally I'd want it in the httpd.conf, and using the exact same rule doesn't work in there.